# Will I receive my payment from admob which are on hold as soon as I verify my address or I will have to wait till 21st?

Tags: admob

My payments on admob is currently at hold because I haven't verified my address, will I receive my payment immediately I verify my address or I will have to wait till 21st ?

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request for payment at any time, but will have to wait until the 21st for the transaction to occur